# After changing element id's to element classes in div tag, keyframes no longer working

Tags: php, html, css, css-animations, keyframe

**Hi Friends**

I have a problem, In order to show multiple rows returned from logged in user, I had to convert my div id tags to div classes (both in my html and corresponding CSS). As a result, my key-frames within my CSS have stopped working.

**My original html code**:

```
 //while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // mysql_fetch_array is deprecated, we need to use mysqli_fetch_array 
       while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {     
        ?>
            <div id='loader-wrapper'>
                <div id='loader'><div id='loader1'> 
                  </div> 
                  </div>
            <p><a  onclick='redirectFunction("<?php echo $res['moduleID']; ?>");'><?php echo $res['moduleID']; ?></a></p>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
```

**My original CSS including keyframes:**

```
 @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600");
    @import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
    *, *:before, *:after {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    html, body {
      height: 100vh;
    }

    body {
      color: #333;
      background: black url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/39132/bg-stars.gif) repeat 0 0;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      height: 100%;
        font-family: sans-serif;
      font-weight: 100;
    }


    .wrapper {
      display: flex;
      min-height: 100%;
    }

    .sidebar {
      position: absolute;
      width: 220px;
    }

    .content {
      flex: 1;
      padding: 30px;
      background:  black url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/39132/bg-stars.gif) repeat 0 0;
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      transition: transform .3s;
    }

    .content.isOpen {
      transform: translate3d(220px, 0, 0);
    }

    .button {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .button:before {
      content: '\f0c9';
      font: 42px fontawesome;
    }

    /* Demo Navigation */
    .title {
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 7px;
      color: #eee;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
      background: #2a2a2a;
    }

    .nav li a {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      padding: 20px 0 20px 50px;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #eee;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
    }

    .nav li a:before {
      font: 14px fontawesome;
      position: absolute;
      top: 19px;
      left: 20px;
    }

    .nav li:nth-child(1) a:before {
      content: '\f00a';
    }

    .nav li:nth-child(2) a:before {
      content: '\f012';
    }

    .nav li:nth-child(3) a:before {
      content: '\f0e8';
    }

    .nav li:nth-child(4) a:before {
      content: '\f0c3';
    }

    .nav li:nth-child(5) a:before {
      content: '\f022';
    }

    .nav li:nth-child(6) a:before {
      content: '\f115';
    }

    .nav li:nth-child(7) a:before {
      content: '\f085';
    }

    .nav li:nth-child(8) a:before {
      content: '\f023';
      left: 23px;
    }

    .nav li a:hover {
      background: #444;
    }

    .nav li a.active {
      box-shadow: inset 5px 0 0 #5b5, inset 6px 0 0 #222;
      background: #444;
    }






    /* Added background Gif, stars are glowing */


    .container{
      display: flex;
       flex-direction: row;
    }
    .container div:first-child(1){
      background-color:#ccffcc;
      flex: 1;
      height:100px;
      width:100px;


    }
    .first {
      -webkit-flex: 2;
              flex: 2:

    }
    .second {
      -webkit-flex: 2;
              flex: 2;

    }
    .third {
      -webkit-flex: 3;
              flex: 3;
    }
    #lnav{
      display:none;
    }
    #rnav{
      display:none;
    }

    .nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none; 
      color:#b3e0ff;
      text-shadow: 0 0 15px #2187e7;
      border: 1px solid #b3e0ff;
       padding:10px;
      margin:10px;
       box-shadow: 0 0 5px #2187e7;

    }



    p{
      z-index: 999;
      margin-left:66px;
      font-size:46px;
      margin-top:-26px;
      color:#fff;/*4db8ff*/
      padding:0px;
      position:relative;
    -webkit-animation: neon2 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
      -moz-animation: neon2 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
      animation: neon2 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    text-shadow: 0 0 15px #b3e0ff;

    }

    p2{
      z-index: 999;
      margin-left:200px;
      font-size:42px;
      margin-top:-26px;
      color:#fff;/*4db8ff*/
      padding:0px;
      position:relative;
    -webkit-animation: neon2 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
      -moz-animation: neon2 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
      animation: neon2 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    text-shadow: 0 0 15px #b3e0ff;

    }

    p3{
      z-index: 999;
      margin-left:260px;
      font-size:42px;
      margin-top:-26px;
      color:#fff;/*4db8ff*/
      padding:0px;
      position:relative;
    -webkit-animation: neon2 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
      -moz-animation: neon2 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
      animation: neon2 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    text-shadow: 0 0 15px #b3e0ff;

    }


    #loader-wrapper{
        position: fixed;
        top: 200px;
        left:18%;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
       margin-left:30px;
        float: left;
    }

     /* I have added more loader-wrapper's to add extra module nodes
    Loader wraooers are floating right instead of left & margin has been changed*/   
    #loader-wrapper1{
        position: fixed;
        top: 200px;
        left:18%;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
       margin-left:30px;
        float: right;
      margin-left: 360px;

    }

    #loader-wrapper2{
        position: fixed;
        top: 200px;
        left:18%;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
       margin-left:30px;
        float: right;
      margin-left: 700px;

    }


    #loader {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: -175px 0 0 -175px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 3px solid transparent;
        border-top-color: #4db8ff;
      border-bottom-color: #b3e0ff;
      border-right-color: #66c2ff;
      border-left-color: #80ccff;
      box-shadow: 0 0 15px #2187e7;

        -webkit-animation: spin 30s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
        animation: spin 30s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    }

    #loader1:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 70px;
        left: 70px;
        right: 70px;
        bottom: 70px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 3px solid transparent;
        border-color: #4398ba;

        border-style:dotted;

        -webkit-animation: spin 18s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
          animation: spin 18s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    }

    #loader1:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 55px;
        left: 55px;
        right: 55px;
        bottom: 55px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border-color: #59c1eb;
       border-width:5px;    
        border-style:double dashed solid dotted ;
      box-shadow: 0 0 40px #2187e7;
        -webkit-animation: spin 60s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
          animation: spin 60s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    }


    #loader:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        left: 15px;
        right: 15px;
        bottom: 15px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 3px solid transparent;
        border-color: #1d5ca9;

        border-style:dotted;

        -webkit-animation: spin 18s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
          animation: spin 18s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    }

    #loader:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 25px;
        left: 25px;
        right: 25px;
        bottom: 25px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 3px solid transparent;
        border-color: #429bc0;
       border-width:5px;    
        border-style:dotted solid;
        -webkit-animation: spin 60s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
          animation: spin 60s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
        0%   {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
            -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* IE 9 */
            transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
        }
        100% {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
            -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* IE 9 */
            transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
        }
    }
    @keyframes spin {
        0%   {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
            -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* IE 9 */
            transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
        }
        100% {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
            -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* IE 9 */
            transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
        }
    }


    @-webkit-keyframes neon2 {
      from {
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #228DFF, 0 0 70px #228DFF, 0 0 80px #228DFF, 0 0 100px #228DFF, 0 0 150px #228DFF;
      }
      to {
        text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #228DFF, 0 0 35px #228DFF, 0 0 40px #228DFF, 0 0 50px #228DFF, 0 0 75px #228DFF;
      }
    }
```

**Here is the original output:**
[image: Orginal output, only one row from multiple returned from logged in user is showing]

**Here is what I changed the html code to:**

```
<div class='loader-wrapper'>
                <div class='loader'><div class='loader1'> 
                  </div> 
                  </div>
            <p><a  onclick='redirectFunction("<?php echo $res['moduleID']; ?>");'><?php echo $res['moduleID']; ?></a></p>
</div>
```

**And what I changed in the CSS:**

```
.loader-wrapper{
    position: fixed;
    top: 200px;
    left:18%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
   margin-left:30px;
    float: left;
}

 /* I have added more loader-wrapper's to add extra module nodes
Loader wrappers are floating right instead of left & margin has been changed*/   
.loader-wrapper1{
    position: fixed;
    top: 200px;
    left:18%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
   margin-left:30px;
    float: right;
  margin-left: 360px;

}

.loader-wrapper2{
    position: fixed;
    top: 200px;
    left:18%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
   margin-left:30px;
    float: right;
  margin-left: 700px;

}


.loader {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: -175px 0 0 -175px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #4db8ff;
  border-bottom-color: #b3e0ff;
  border-right-color: #66c2ff;
  border-left-color: #80ccff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #2187e7;

    -webkit-animation: spin 30s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
    animation: spin 30s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}

.loader1:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 70px;
    right: 70px;
    bottom: 70px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-color: #4398ba;

    border-style:dotted;

    -webkit-animation: spin 18s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
      animation: spin 18s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}

.loader1:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    left: 55px;
    right: 55px;
    bottom: 55px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-color: #59c1eb;
   border-width:5px;    
    border-style:double dashed solid dotted ;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px #2187e7;
    -webkit-animation: spin 60s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
      animation: spin 60s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}


.loader:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-color: #1d5ca9;

    border-style:dotted;

    -webkit-animation: spin 18s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
      animation: spin 18s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}

.loader:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
    right: 25px;
    bottom: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-color: #429bc0;
   border-width:5px;    
    border-style:dotted solid;
    -webkit-animation: spin 60s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
      animation: spin 60s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}
```

**Here is the output now, I am now outputting all rows returned from logged in user but my keyframes have stopped working**

[image: Keyframes not working output]

Any Idea where I've gone wrong?

---

### EDIT

**Added my resulting html:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Homepage</title>

  <!--Cascasing stylesheets -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<style type="text/css">
  body {
  margin: 0;
  background: black url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/39132/bg-stars.gif) repeat 0 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}
</style>

</head>
<!-- Encorporated module nodes, number 1 in readme.txt that is wrapped around number 5 from readme.txt which is the sidebar -->

<body>
  <div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='sidebar'>
    <div class='title'>
      Menu
    </div>
    <ul class='nav'>
      <li>
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="index.php">Chat</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a>Settings</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='accounts/logout.php'>Logout</a><br/>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class='content isOpen'>
    <a class='button'></a>
    <!-- Session variables used from login functionality, number 9 of readme.txt-->
     <!-- With guidance from  http://blog.chapagain.com.np/crud-create-read-update-delete-php-mysql-login-register/ -->
        <br/>
        <br/>
        Welcome James ! <a href='logout.php'>Logout</a><br/>
        <br/>
        <!-- <a href='index.php'>View and Add Products</a> -->
        <div class="second">

                    <div class='loader-wrapper'>
                <div class='loader'><div class='loader1'> 
                  </div> 
                  </div>
            <p><a  onclick='redirectFunction("1");'>1</a></p>
            </div>
                    <div class='loader-wrapper'>
                <div class='loader'><div class='loader1'> 
                  </div> 
                  </div>
            <p><a  onclick='redirectFunction("2");'>2</a></p>
            </div>
                    <div class='loader-wrapper'>
                <div class='loader'><div class='loader1'> 
                  </div> 
                  </div>
            <p><a  onclick='redirectFunction("3");'>3</a></p>
            </div>

    </div>
        <br/><br/>
  </div>
</div>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Do you have any idea how to get the values 1,2 & 3 that are returned next to each-other in three different circles?

Comment: Hi @sglessard The blue circles won't seem to work when they're declared as classes as opposed to id which needs to be done in order for all values to be returned.

Comment: Seems fine, i've tested your HTML/CSS and I see the `.loader1` circles https://jsfiddle.net/jurk979f/7/

Comment: In your code, both loader wrapper and loader are set as id as opposed to class

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jurk979f/8/

Comment: Will it work for you when more than one moduleID is returned? I'll edit the post with the code needed

Comment: @sglessard Edited now

Comment: Seems it does https://jsfiddle.net/jurk979f/12/ you can fork the jsfiddle to test stuff

Comment: @sglessard this is what I was getting originally (if you see top screen shot in post), I'm trying to get the values 1,2 & 3 that are returned next to eachother in three different circles. Any thoughts? Thanks so much for your help so far

Comment: Oh I thought the problem was the missing circles. Remove `position:fixed` from the `.loader-wrapper` class?

Comment: The problem is the circles disappeared when I was fixing the code from id to class in order for more than one value to be returned (apologies if that was not clear enough) @sglessard